# Не работает код программы pascal, которая должна решать квадратные уравнения

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

Задача: Написать программу, которая решает квадратные уравнения(изучаем Паскаль в рамках школьной программы).
Пишу такой код:

```
program X;
  var a, b, c: integer;
  var D: integer;
  var x, x1, x2: real;
  begin
  writeln('Введите первое число: ');
  readln(a);
  writeln('Введите второе число: ');
  readln(b);
  writeln('Введите третье число: ');
  readln(c);
  
  
  D:=b*b-4*a*c;
  writeln('');
  write('Дискриминант равен: ');
  writeln(D);
  
  if D<0
    then writeln('Нет корней');
  if D=0
    then x:=-b/(2*a);
    write('Один корень: ');
    writeln(x);
  if D>0
    then x1:=-b+sqrt(D)/(2*a);
         x2:=-b-sqrt(D)/(2*a);
         writeln('Два корня');
         writeln(x1);
         write(x2);
end.
```

Программа не работает, выдает ошибку «Ошибка выполнения. Line:column 32:20
При вызове функции или процедуры "Sqrt(Real):Real"»

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, оно хочет (что странно)

```
 var D: real;
```

Это, небось, фряха выкаблучивается?

Кроме того, не хватает скобок операторных и обычных здесь:

```
 then begin
    x1:=(-b+sqrt(D))/(2*a);
    x2:=(-b-sqrt(D))/(2*a);
    writeln('Два корня');
    writeln(x1);
    write(x2);
 end;
```

И операторных после `if D=0 then`

И программу надо переименовать.

https://ideone.com/fvRgpL

И по стилю - используйте `if-else`, чтобы понятно было, что ветки не независимы.